# angularjs ag-grid does not show row data

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid

I am using ag-grid to return 1 row of data from a server.  The data is returning from the server and it is set in the grid but the data is not displaying.
This is my grid:

```
$scope.lastResultGridOptions = {
    rowData: $scope.jobResult,
    suppressCellSelection: true,
    suppressSorting: true,
    enableFilter: true,
    enableColResize: true,
    angularCompileRows: true,
    angularCompileHeaders: true,
    suppressMenuHide: true,
    columnDefs: [{
        field: 'StartDate',
        filter: 'text',
        headerName: 'Start Date',
        cellClass: 'wrap-text',
        minWidth: 10
    }, {
        field: 'EndDate',
        filter: 'text',
        headerName: 'End Date',
        cellClass: 'wrap-text',
        minWidth: 40
    }, {
        field: 'IsSuccess',
        filter: 'text',
        headerName: 'Result Status',
        cellClass: 'wrap-text',
        minWidth: 40
    }, {
        field: 'DateCompleted',
        filter: 'text',
        headerName: 'Date Completed',
        cellClass: 'wrap-text',
        minWidth: 40
    }]
};
```

This function is called during initialization:

```
$scope.refreshLastResultGrid = function () {
jobResult.paged().$promise.then(function (results) {
    $scope.jobResult = results;
    $scope.lastResultGridOptions.rowData = $scope.jobResult;

    if ($scope.lastResultGridOptions.api) {
        $scope.lastResultGridOptions.api.setRowData();
        $scope.lastResultGridOptions.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
    }
}, function (error) {
 $scope.messageModalVariables = {
messageTitle: 'Error Refreshing Job Result',
messageDisplay: 'API Error. Could not retrieve job results.',
messageType: 'Error',
okIsHidden: false,
yesNoIsHidden: true
};
$scope.openMessageModal($scope.messageModalVariables);
        });
    };

$scope.refreshLastResultGrid();
```

This is the service call to the server that returns the row:

```
angular.module('vAnalyzeApp.services')
.factory('JobResult', function($resource, configSettings) {
 var jobresult = $resource(configSettings.apiServiceUrl + 'api/v1/jobresult', {}, {
   'paged': {
     method: 'GET',
     isArray: false,
     transformResponse: function(data, headers) {
      var count = headers('Count');
      return {
        count: angular.fromJson(count),
        results: angular.fromJson(data)
      };
    }
   }
 });
 return jobresult;
});
```

I debug in the `refreshLastResultGrid` function and the `results` come back from the server and are set to the `$scope.lastResultGridOptions.rowData`.
The `setRowData()` function is completed without error but the data is not shown on the grid.
Here is a screen shot of the grid:
[image]

Why is the data not displaying in the grid?

**UPDATE**
The result object is:

```
public class JobParameterDto
{
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public string SourceDB { get; set; }
    public string TargetDB { get; set; }
    public Nullable<DateTime> DateCompleted { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> IsSuccess { get; set; }
}
```

When I view the result object this is the correct data returned:

- StartDate: '01/01/2016T00:00:00'
- EndDate: '11/01/2016T00:00:00'
- TargetDB: 'MainDB'
- SourceDB: 'WrhDB'
- IsSuccess: null
- DateCompleted: null

Comment: What about $scope.jobResult = results.data;

Comment: results.data is the JobParameterDto object shown above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use `api.setRowData` to set grid rows. Make sure `results.data` is an `Array` - ag-grid expect `rowData` to be an `Array`.

```
...
jobResult.paged().$promise.then(function (results) {
    $scope.jobResult = results instanceof Array?results:[results];
    if ($scope.lastResultGridOptions.api) {
        $scope.lastResultGridOptions.api.setRowData($scope.jobResult);
        $scope.lastResultGridOptions.api.refreshView();
        $scope.lastResultGridOptions.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
    }
}, function (error){
...
```

Comment: same result...no data

Comment: can u share the sample result object?

Comment: I added the object data above.  There are 2 fields that are `null`.  The other fields have text.

Comment: is it an array? could you plz share the whole result object structure?

Comment: It is not an array but 1 object.  The result object is JobParameterDto listed above.

Comment: as @ajaiJothi says, the rowData needs to be an array of JSON objects

Comment: That did not work either. Debugging the code..`result` showed the object with the correct items set (StartDate, EndDate, etc).  But `result.data` was undefined.  I am using the same code for another grid but there are multiple rows.  I use the method `.query` to force an array and the row data displays correctly.  This grid has 1 row.  I return 1 object.  The data is returned and the `jobResult` object is set but the grid does not display the data.

Comment: could you please share exact `response` getting in browser.

Comment: I read your comment closer.  I needed to change the return type from my API to a List.  Because as you said the grid has to have an array of rows.  But I only need 1 row, so I will have to limit the row number to 1.

Comment: I need to convert the result to an array.  How can I do that?

Comment: updated the code plz check.... `$scope.jobResult = results instanceof Array?results:[results]` this actually does the trick